# Opengl vertex coordinates for perspective projection

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I need to use perspective transformation but I can't understand how to define model coordinates of sprite. If I use orthogonal projection I can define coordinate of each vertex as number pixels on screen. But with perspective projection I can't.

Orthogonal projection:

```
glm::ortho<GLfloat>(0.0f, screen_width, screen_height, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f));
```

Perspective:

```
glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.f), (float)screen_width / (float)screen_height, 0.1f, 100.f);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (std140) uniform Matrices
{
    mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
    mat4 ViewMatrix;
    mat4 ModelMatrix;
};

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoords;

out vec2 TextureCoords;

void main()
{
    TextureCoords = inTexCoords;
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.f, 1.0);
}
```

For example

```
        vertices[1] = 0.f;
        vertices[8] = 0.f;
        vertices[12] = 0.f;
        vertices[13] = 0.f;

        for (GLuint i = 0; i < m_totSprites; ++i) {
            // Vertex pos
            vertices[0] = m_clips[i].w;
            vertices[4] = vertices[0];
            vertices[5] = m_clips[i].h;
            vertices[9] = vertices[5];

            // Texture pos
            vertices[2] = (m_clips[i].x + m_clips[i].w) / tw;
            vertices[3] = (m_clips[i].y + m_clips[i].h) / th;
            vertices[6] = (m_clips[i].x + m_clips[i].w) / tw;
            vertices[7] = m_clips[i].y / th;
            vertices[10] = m_clips[i].x / tw;
            vertices[11] = m_clips[i].y / th;
            vertices[14] = m_clips[i].x / tw;
            vertices[15] = (m_clips[i].y + m_clips[i].h) / th;
```

It works well with orthogonal projection. How can I define vertex coordinates for perspective?

What the different with model coordinates in orthogonal projection and perspective? Why in first case it's easy to set coords of vertices as pixel sizes, but in all examples with perspective they normalized between -0.5 to 0.5? It's necessary?

Comment: What is the question? What does not work? What is the actual behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Nothing appear. Sprite centered at screen center. With orthogonal projection it works well

Comment: Very likely the sprite is clipped by the near plane of the perspective projection. The geometry need to be in between the near (0.1) and far (100.0) plane, otherwise it is clipped. But this is just a guess, because I don't know your view and model matrix. See [LearnOpenGL - Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera)

Comment: Sprite z coordinates is zero. In vertex shader i tried to use different z values from -10 to 10. Also it works with frustum: glm::frustum(0.f, (float)screen_width, (float)screen_height, 0.f, 1.0f, -1.f);

Comment: For perspective projection, the values for the near and far plane must be positive! 0 < near < far. See [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum)

Comment: "I need to use perspective transformation but i can't understand how to define model coordinates of sprite." Why do you need to do that? For sprites, it makes little sense. And if you are in a situation where it really makes sense, you would know how to set it up.

Comment: They positive. I can't understand about vertex coords. They need to be normalized(from -0.5 to 0.5) or may be pixel size? In orthogonal projection they can be not normalized. Can i do the same with perpspective?

Comment: " If i use orthogonal projection i can define coordinate of each vertex as number pixels on screen. But with perspective projection i can't. " Why do you think you can't? Of course you can set up a perspective projection so that one particular plane will exactly match your window space pixel coordinates. But the question again is: why would you want to do that? It wouldn't gain you anything compared to staying with ortho projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I was misunderstood difference between orthogonal and perspective projections. As I understood now all vertices mapped initially in NDC for perspective projection. Then they moved, scaled, etc with model matrix. Pixel perfect rendering can be realized only with some constant depth or with orthogonal. I't unuseful for 3D with perspective projection.

Answer (score -3):

if you have projection matrix you need a view matrix too.
there's `glm::lookAt()` for ex
i use this combo usually

```
glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(-1.2484,0.483,1.84384), glm::vec3(-0.3801, -0.4183,-3.15),glm::vec3( 0., 0.2,-00.))
glm::perspective(45., 1., 1.2, 300.) 
glm::mat4(1.)
```

Comment: "if you have projection matrix you need a view matrix too." No, that is not strictly necessary. A view matrix is most useful if you want some moveable camera. The math is well-defined if you use a projection matrix alone, and for stuff like sprite rendering mentioned in the question, it might be perfectly fine. The fixed values you put there don't make any sense for a generic case, anyway.

Comment: My view and model matrix is diagonal 1's mat4(1.f) initially. Model then transformed to position at screen center.

Comment: it's necessary if you gonna to see something.

Comment: No it is not. That's simply a factually wrong statement youre giving here. If you draw without a view matrix, you technically draw directly n eye space, and of course can set up your vertex coordinates accordingly.

Comment: As i understood, for perspective projection much easier to use normalized(-0.5 to 0.5) coords in model space, than tune perspective parameters to match with pixel size, as i did with orthogonal projection (use non-normalized coords for vertices). It's right?

Comment: @derhass what you understand by "defined"? if otho isn't enough then it's needed or you'll fail to tune it all

Comment: @derhass really? show example may be. do you need monitor at least?

Comment: No idea what you're even talking about. The numbers you gave in this answers just define an arbitrary camera location, looking at an arbitrary point, combined with an up vector `( 0., 0.2,-00.)` which should raise some red flags to anyone  reading this code, plus an projection matrix which doesn't even match the aspect ratio. Those numbers have actually nothing to do with the vertex coordinates in the question, and putting your matrices in will still have the quads in the question totally off-screen

Comment: @derhass ' draw directly n eye space' .  wtf problems you have with up vec?

Comment: @Aleksey i don't understand a goal there so can't say. range is [-1.0 ... 1.0]